# Checking for value within same type in python

Tags: python

```
a = 0
if a == False:
   print a
```

in php I can say:

```
$a = 0;
if $a === false {
    echo $a;
}
```

The triple === in php check for the value within the same type, thus making the integer 0 not be read as a boolean value False
How can I do this in python? I would like to differentiate between 0 the integer and False the boolean value in a simple if statement.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [`is`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.is_) keyword in that case. It's the identity operator, the same as `===` in PHP.

```
>>> a = 0
>>> if a is False:
...     print a
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`type()` will give you the type of an object. But if you're worried about distinguishing between `0` and `False` then perhaps you should use `None` instead.